# ¿Se puede llamar un método en el método __getattribute__?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Esta es mi clase:

```
class User():

    ...

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name not in ['create_user', 'authenticate_user']:
            x = super().__getattribute__('authenticate_user')
            print(x)

        return super().__getattribute__(name)
```

Quiero obtener el valor del método `authenticate_user`, pero no puedo.

En esta parte:

```
x = super().__getattribute__('authenticate_user')
```

Solo obtengo el método, pero quiero ejecutarlo para asi obtener el valor que retorna dicho método. Pero al momento de ejecutarlo:

```
x = super().__getattribute__('authenticate_user')()
```

Obtengo un error de `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`.

Y no tengo ni la menor idea de como llamar el método sin que me de ese error o alguna solucion.

¿Hay alguna manera de llamar dicho método en el método `__getattribute__`? ¿Alguna solución?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La respuesta es si, pero con mucho, mucho, mucho cuidado...

El método `__getattribute__` junto a su hermano `__setattr__` son quizás dos de los métodos especiales más complicados de implementar y en los que más cuidado hay que tener.

El problema con `__getattribute__` suele ser casi siempre el mismo, lo implementamos, creemos que todo es perfecto, ejecutamos y ¡boom! la recursión infinita.

La causa y su explicación son realmente muy sencillas, pero aún conociéndolo perfectamente es fácil cometer algún desliz. Lo que hay que marcarse siempre a fuego es:

> El método **`__getattribute__` es siempre el primer método llamado cuando se accede a un atributo o método** ([para el lenguaje en éste caso es indiferente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/351244/15089)) de un objeto.

Es por tanto el punto de entrada para resolver el acceso a tributos mediante "dot notation", si no encuentra el atributo delega en los demás métodos de la cadena hasta terminar con `__getattr__` si está implementado.

**La causa de la recursión infinita es siempre que llamamos a un método o accedemos a un atributo desde el propio `__getattribute__` de forma directa o indirecta.** Si desde el propio `__getattribute__` se intenta acceder a un atributo de la instancia con `self.atributo` por ejemplo, al resolver `self.atributo` se invoca a `self.__getattribute__("atributo")`, dentro del cual se vuelve a intentar acceder a `self.atributo`, lo que invoca de nuevo a `self.__getattribute__("atributo")`...

La forma de evitarlo es delegar en el método `__getattribute__` de una clase padre la obtención de la referencia al atributo/método, en última instancia será `object.__getattribute__` si no heredamos de nada. Lo normal es usar `super()` para ello, el cuál retorna un objeto proxy al método del padre que toque, según MRO, que podemos usar para llamarlo.

---

### Caso 1

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, user):
        self.user = user

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        x = self.user
        print(x)
        return super().__getattribute__(name)
```

> ```
> >>> user = User("FJSevilla")
> >>> user.user
> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
> ```

Mal, muy mal, `x = self.user` ocasiona que se vuelva a llamar a `__getattribute__` (`self.__getattribute__("user")`) desde él mismo...

Pregunta relacionada:

- [RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/351477/15089)

---

### Caso 2

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, user):
        self.user = user

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        x = super().__getattribute__("user")
        print(x)
        return super().__getattribute__(name)
```

> ```
> >>> user = User("FJSevilla")
> >>> user.user
> "FJSevilla"
> ```

Bien, al delegar en el método del padre evitamos la llamada recursiva.

---

### Caso 3

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, user):
        self.user = user

    def authenticate_user(self):
        return "FJSevilla"

    def foo(self):
        pass

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name not in ['create_user', 'authenticate_user']:
            x = super().__getattribute__('authenticate_user')()
            print(x)

        return super().__getattribute__(name)
```

> ```
> >>> user = User("FJSevilla")
> >>> user.foo
> "FJSevilla"
> ```

Ningún problema, al igual que antes se delega en el padre la resolución del método `self.autentificate_user` y no hay llamada recursiva.

---

### Caso 4

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, user):
        self.user = user

    def authenticate_user(self):
        return self.user

    def foo(self):
        pass

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name not in ['create_user', 'authenticate_user']:
            x = super().__getattribute__('authenticate_user')()
            print(x)

        return super().__getattribute__(name)
```

> ```
> >>> user = User("FJSevilla")
> >>> user.foo
> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
> ```

Otra vez... Solo hemos cambiado:

```
def authenticate_user(self):
    return "FJSevilla"
```

por:

```
def authenticate_user(self):
    return self.user    # <<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

pero el error es es muy similar al caso 1, solo que en éste caso el acceso a un atributo desde `__getattribute__` no es de forma directa, es el método que `super().__getattribute__` te retorna el que provoca que se llame a `__getatributte__` de nuevo por culpa de `return self.user`.

No muestras la implementación del método `authenticate_user` pero puedo afirmar con bastante seguridad que dicho método accede a atributos o métodos de la instancia en algún momento y por tanto hace uso de `__getattribute__`.

---

### Caso 5

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, user):
        self.user = user

    def authenticate_user(self):
        return self.user

    def foo(self):
        pass

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name not in ['create_user', 'authenticate_user', "user"]:
            #                                               ^^^^^^
            x = super().__getattribute__('authenticate_user')()
            print(x)

        return super().__getattribute__(name)
```

> ```
>     >>> user = User("FJSevilla")
>     >>> user.foo
>     "FJSevilla"
> ```

---

### Caso 6

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, user):
        self.user = user

    def authenticate_user(self):
        return self.user

    def foo(self):
        pass

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name not in ['create_user', 'authenticate_user', "user"]:
            #                                               ^^^^^^
            x = super().__getattribute__('authenticate_user')()
            print(x)

        return super().__getattribute__(name)
```

> ```
>     >>> user = User("FJSevilla")
>     >>> user.foo
>     "FJSevilla"
> ```

---

### Caso 7

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, user):
        self.user = user  # Mal

    def get_user(self):
        return self.user

    def authenticate_user(self):
        return super().__getattribute__("get_user")() # Bien

    def foo(self):
        pass

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name not in ['create_user', 'authenticate_user']:
            x = super().__getattribute__('authenticate_user')() # Bien
            print(x)

        return super().__getattribute__(name)
```

> ```
>     >>> user = User("FJSevilla")
>     >>> user.foo
>     RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
> ```

---

### Caso N

Dependiendo de la implementación concreta existirán muchas posibles soluciones, pero la idea de todas ellas es la misma siempre, **evitar a toda costa que cualquier cosa que llames o referencies en `__getattribute__` termine en cualquier momento llamando también a `self.__getattibute__` sin que exista un cortocircuito en algún punto**.

---

### ¿Qué pasa con los builtins y operadores que usan métodos de la instancia?

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, user):
        self.user = user

    def authenticate_user(self):
        return str(self)

    def foo(self):
        pass

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name not in ['create_user', 'authenticate_user', 'user']:
            x = super().__getattribute__('authenticate_user')()
            print(x)
        return super().__getattribute__(name)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

> ```
> >>> user = User("FJSevilla")
> >>> user.foo
> FJSevilla
> ```

Se podría pensar que dado que `str(self)` llama a `self.__str__` tendríamos de nuevo el problema que nos atañe... Pues no, `str`, `implementado` en C, no referencia directamente al método usando la implementación de `__getattribute__` de la instancia, evitando el problema. Pasaría igual con `repr`, `sorted`, `print`, operadores como `==` (`__eq__`), `!=` (`__ne__`), etc. Ésta es las razones por la que no se debe llamar  a `__str__` o `__repr__`, `__hash__`, etc directamente, sino mediante sus builtins.

Eso si, no nos protege de que en la implementación del propio `__str__` se acceda a atributos que causen de nuevo la llamada recursiva, si en el ejemplo anterior cambiamos:

```
if name not in ['create_user', 'authenticate_user', 'user']:
```

por:

```
if name not in ['create_user', 'authenticate_user']:
```

la volvemos a liar.

Comment: Se me paso por alto esto, al parecer hay que pensar mas de 2 veces al utilizar el método `__getattribute__` xD. Por otra parte el método `authenticate_user` accede a varios atributos de instancia, y la verdad no veo optimo obtener dichos atributos atraves del método `__getattribute__` del padre. Tendré que buscar otra solución, gracias!